# DataStage. Change some columns using 2 files

Tags: database, datastage

I have two source files. They both have the nearly same layout. I have to match FILE 1 column A with the FILE 2 column A (pretty much a left outer join). If it matched, the FILE 1 columns G,H and I, have to get the same columns of FILE 2. If it don't matched, no alteration have to be made, but it still have to go to output link.

I think Lookup Stage can do that, but I don't know how to edit it to change just this specifies columns in case of matching the key column, and the non-maching rows pass untouched (not going to reject link or getting null, just going with previous data).

Someone can enlighten me in this question? Sorry by the noob question and English's mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with a Lookup stage, set the Lookup Failed rule to Continue and ensure that any output columns from the reference input are Nullable through to the output.

Or use a Join stage to effect the left outer join.

Comment: But, if I do that, the non-match rows are gonna to be null, don't they?

Comment: Yes they are - if they had been nullable in th input of the stage (this is different to SQL). You need a Transformer to decide for the content of the G,H,I column. You could also add a column with a static value to the right input of the left join to easily see if it matched or not - this might help.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case seems to indicate that you should just be using a join stage instead. You can set it to a left outer join and this should give you the results that you need.